# Emacs window management

Tags: emacs, window

I want to achieve the following when a buffer is displayed in `GNU Emacs`:

1. it should never split my windows;
2. if the buffer is already opened in a window it should reuse it, otherwise it should use the current window.

---

### Partial solution

- setting `pop-up-windows` to `nil` will solve the point `1`;
- setting `same-window-regexps` to `'("^\*")` will solve the second part of the point `2`, but it's in contrast with the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that is possible to customize the behavior of the function `display-buffer` by setting the variable `display-buffer-function`.

This function seems to do what I want (surely it needs some cleanup but it works):

```
(defun my-display-buffer (BUFFER-OR-NAME &optional NOT-THIS-WINDOW)
  (catch 'return
    ;; search the buffer in the existing windows
    (let ((windows (window-list)))
      (while (first windows)
        ;; found
        (if (eq (window-buffer (first windows)) BUFFER-OR-NAME)
            (throw 'return
                   ;; if minibuffer doesn't select the window
                   (if (eq (selected-window) (minibuffer-window))
                       (first windows)
                     (select-window (first windows)))))
        ;; next window
        (setq windows (rest windows))))
    ;; otherwise use current
    (if (eq (selected-window) (minibuffer-window))
        ;; if minubuffer
        (progn
          (select-window (minibuffer-selected-window))
          (switch-to-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME)
          (select-window (minibuffer-window)))
      ;; if regular window
      (progn
        (switch-to-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME)
        (selected-window)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `(setq pop-up-windows nil)` seems to do what you want.
2. I don't think you should have to do much here. At least, the help commands already exhibit this behavior.

Comment: You're right, it seems that `switch-to-buffer-other-window` is used pretty deep in the internals of the help code. You could try advising switch-to-buffer-other-window to use switch-to-buffer for certain contexts. That should give you a start.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look in that direction, but note `*Help*` it's just an example.

Comment: That's true, but since `switch-to-buffer-other-window` is likely used in most cases where you see the undesired behavior, advising it will modify all those cases, conditionally if you like.

Comment: It seems that customizing the variable `display-buffer-function` will do the trick, see [my own answer](http://superuser.com/questions/244036/emacs-window-management/245339#245339).

Comment: Good find there. That is definitely preferable to my suggestion to use advise.