# Emacs window management and switching buffers

Tags: emacs, window-manager, buffer

In emacs I like to have 4 windows open at a time. For example, I frequently have a python interpreter in the first window, my python code I am editing in the second window, mysql in the 3rd window and scratch in the 4th window.

My issue is, whenever I run a command in the minibuffer while in say window 2 it does not open the new buffer created by the command in window 2. It picks some other window. For example, if I am in window 1 and type `M-x run-python` it will open the python interpreter in any of the other windows. I would like it to open the python interpreter in the current window (in this case window 1). I came across this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/244036/emacs-window-management) which mentions the variable `pop-up-windows` I set this variable to `nil` as recommended but nothing has changed. I believe my issue has more to do with "switching" windows.

1. How can I get a new buffer to be displayed in the window in which it was invoked?
2. Can this functionality be set for all programs? (or most)

If you need any more information, let me know. All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/StickyWindows

Answer (score 1):

In general it is the individual command that determines which window to use for the display. However, you might be able to make some general adjustments by customizing user option `display-buffer-alist` (if it exists in your version of Emacs --- it is fairly recent).